# z3 sort mismatch for different bytes of the same variable

Tags: python, z3, solver, z3py

I'm simulating the behaviour of an algorithm using z3 python package, however I'm encountering problems using a bitwise XOR.

At first I define

```
    class State:
        def __init__(self):
            self.state = [0] * 0x270
            self.index = 0

    def mag(i):
        return z3.If(i == 0, 0x0, 0x9908b0df)

seed = z3.BitVec('seed', 32)
s= State()
```

And the script goes on, however when I run the Solver I get a `z3.z3types.Z3Exception: sort mismatch` caused by trying to execute the `__xor__` in the line

```
s.state[i] = s.state[i + 0x18d] ^ ((s.state[i + 1] & 0x7fffffff | s.state[i] & 0x80000000) >> 1) ^ mag((s.state[1] & 1) *8)
```

Here every entry in s.state depends on the symbolic value of the seed.

I'm a beginner with these kind of solver and I'm not sure what exactly causes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in that line by itself. You can verify it by running the following:

```py
from z3 import *

class State:
   def __init__(self):
     self.state = [BitVec('x', 32)] * 0x270
     self.index = 0

seed = z3.BitVec('seed', 32)
s= State()

i = 87
s.state[i] = s.state[i + 0x18d] ^ ((s.state[i + 1] & 0x7fffffff | s.state[i] & 0x80000000) >> 1)
print(s.state[I])
```

This prints:

```py
x ^ (x & 2147483647 | x & 2147483648) >> 1
```

So, the problem must be originating from elsewhere in your program. You need to reduce it down to a minimal example (see here for guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and hopefully in the process of simplification you'll find the issue yourself. If not, feel free to post again with a full-example that others can replicate.

### Regarding the `mag` function:

Note that your `mag` function simply uses integers, so z3 cannot deduce that it's about bit-vectors. This is the reason why you're getting a sort-mismatch. To avoid the issue, define `mag` as follows:

```py
def mag(i):
    return z3.If(i == 0, z3.BitVecVal(0x0, 64), z3.BitVecVal(0x9908b0df, 64))
```

Note the use of `BitVecVal`. This should fix the issue.

Comment: I have added the relevant code, there was actually a long series of xor operations and I mixed the operands. I solved the problem by replacing the z3.IF with a simple multiplication, however I'm still interested in the technical reason why z3 raised an error

Comment: Your `mag` function returns an `Int`; causing the issue. See my update on how to write it so it returns a proper bit-vector.